# Failed to install JBOSS and GlassFish on Eclipse Indigo - For Java EE developers

Tags: eclipse, jboss, glassfish, eclipse-indigo

I install Eclipe Indigo for Java EE devlopers.
I tried to install apllication sever glassfish or Jboss and consecutive failed to install them.

1.Create new server - select Download addtional server adapters
2.select the JBoss AS Tools or racle Glass Fish Sever Tools
3.Both installation failed:

The Glass fish error log was:

After 5 minutes of installaion Ive got the following failure message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
  phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
  action=).
  Unable to read repository at


http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/indigo/wtp/plugins/oracle.eclipse.tools.doc.javaee5_1.0.0.201111040904.jar.
Read timed out
```

.................

The JBOS failure was:

```
`Unable to read repository at
 http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/webtools/indigo/plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.jdt.integration_3.2.1.v20111022-0843-H32-M4.jar.
Read timed out
```

.............

Answer (score 2):

I normally download eclipse plugin package and install from local machine. You could try same approach.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error while trying to install Glassfish 3 in eclipse. So first I added the latest JDK in Installed JREs and again tried to install Glassfish server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on some AS documentation, and I'm running Eclipse Indigo with JBoss Application Server 7.0.x, extended with the addition of [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools). If you haven't used them before, they are essentially a set of plugins that extend the application framework of Eclipse. Read more per the FAQ [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossToolsGeneralFAQ).

The steps I followed were per the [installation guide](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_3.html), which contains all the links for Eclipse and the tooling required. I used the update URL method, and if you need it, cou can grab Jboss Application Server 7 [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads). I would recommend trying out a 7.0.x version first, as these have been confirmed as working. You might also like to check out [JBoss Developer Studio](http://www.jboss.com/products/devstudio/).